# Problems updating column names in R as part of a function

Tags: r

I'm trying to scrape a table from Baseball-Reference and then clean it up as part of an importing function. I am able to perform the necessary steps when I run my code line by line, but when I add it to a function, the process of naming NA column names returns only a vector of the names instead of a table or data frame with the new column names.

When I run...

```
initial_clean_3 <- function(website) {
x <- read_html(website) %>% html_table()
y <- x[[1]]
names(y) <- c("Gm#", "Date", "Boxscore", "Tm", "Home", "Opp", "W/L", "R", "RA", "Inn", "W-L", "Rank", 
             "GB", "Win", "Loss", "Save", "Time", "D/N", "Attendance", "cLI", "Streak",         
             "Orig. Scheduled")
# or
#colnames(y)[3] <- "Boxscore"

Diamondbacks <- initial_clean(https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/ARI/2019-schedule-scores.shtml)
```

I am given either just a vector with the new list of column names, or just a singular value when I run colnames with the given index.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you just missed to `return(y)`?

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your function ends at `names(y) <- ...`

Just add a return inside :

```
initial_clean_3 <- function(website) {
x <- read_html(website) %>% html_table()
y <- x[[1]]
names(y) <- c("Gm#", "Date", "Boxscore", "Tm", "Home", "Opp", "W/L", "R", "RA", "Inn", "W-L", "Rank", 
             "GB", "Win", "Loss", "Save", "Time", "D/N", "Attendance", "cLI", "Streak",         
             "Orig. Scheduled")

return(y)
}
```

Or

```
initial_clean_3 <- function(website) {
x <- read_html(website) %>% html_table()
y <- x[[1]]
names(y) <- c("Gm#", "Date", "Boxscore", "Tm", "Home", "Opp", "W/L", "R", "RA", "Inn", "W-L", "Rank", 
             "GB", "Win", "Loss", "Save", "Time", "D/N", "Attendance", "cLI", "Streak",         
             "Orig. Scheduled")

y
}
```

Also mind that you are using `initial_clean` and not `initial_clean_3` in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to define what the function should return. Just add `return(y)` at the end of the function, like this:

```
initial_clean <- function(website) {
  x <- read_html(website) %>% html_table()
  y <- x[[1]]
  names(y) <- c("Gm#", "Date", "Boxscore", "Tm", "Home", "Opp", "W/L", "R", "RA", "Inn", "W-L", "Rank", 
                "GB", "Win", "Loss", "Save", "Time", "D/N", "Attendance", "cLI", "Streak",         
                "Orig. Scheduled")
  
  return(y)
}
```

**The Result:**

```
Diamondbacks <- initial_clean("https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/ARI/2019-schedule-scores.shtml")

head(Diamondbacks)
  Gm#             Date Boxscore  Tm Home Opp W/L  R RA Inn W-L Rank  GB      Win    Loss
1   1 Thursday, Mar 28 boxscore ARI    @ LAD   L  5 12     0-1    4 1.0      Ryu Greinke
2   2   Friday, Mar 29 boxscore ARI    @ LAD   W  5  4  13 1-1    3 1.0 Andriese  Garcia
3   3 Saturday, Mar 30 boxscore ARI    @ LAD   L  5 18     1-2    4 1.0    Maeda  Godley
4   4   Sunday, Mar 31 boxscore ARI    @ LAD   L  7  8     1-3    4 2.0    Floro  Hirano
5 Gm#            April           Tm      Opp W/L  R RA Inn W-L Rank  GB      Win    Loss
6   5    Monday, Apr 1 boxscore ARI    @ SDP   W 10  3     2-3    3 1.0    Kelly  Strahm
        Save Time D/N Attendance  cLI Streak Orig. Scheduled
1            2:49   D     53,086 1.08      -                
2    Holland 6:05   N     42,266  .99      +                
3            3:14   N     50,626 1.06      -                
4     Jansen 3:29   D     43,815 1.04     --                
5       Save Time D/N Attendance  cLI Streak Orig. Scheduled
6 Duplantier 3:04   N     18,683  .98      +
```